# Restore of database failed .bak file SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, restore

I have faced following error during restoring database:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore failed for Server  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: There is insufficient free space on disk volume 'C:\' to create the database. The database requires 92382625792 additional free bytes, while only 42311290880 bytes are available. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Database `.bak` file size is 697 MB and we have around 39 GB free space on server C drive.

Please anyone let me know, what should I do?

Comment: Confirm that the "C" drive you are looking at and the one it is actually restoring to are the same. If you're connected via SSMS to another instance and using its "C" drive rather than the machine you are running the SSMS query from, you need to ensure the SQL Server instance "C" drive has sufficient space for the BAK file it's restoring. The message and issue are pretty clear, and also 92382625792 bytes as per the error message is about 92 GB and NOT 697 MB so something is not right for what you're explaining and the error message so double-check you're restoring the correct BAK file as well.

Comment: We have only 1 C Drive on server and now 39 GB free space available

Comment: The BAK file is 92 GB so that's not going to work so what other options are available to you? Do you need to shrink log files down on some of the DBs also on the "C" drive to get some space back perhaps? Is this a development box or something?

Comment: The files that were backed up were obviously much larger than 697MB.  The files may have been mostly empty, the backup may be compressed, but the fact remains that the files SQL Server needs to create (Based on the database that was backed up) require 92GB of space.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the actual size of the database files which you can check by running

`RESTORE FILELIST ONLY FROM <backup_device>`

This will give you information about the [files contained in the backup and their sizes in bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx)

You need the same space available on the server as the database file size, the backups can be compressed.

Now you need to free up more space on c: on the server but I would recommend that you add drives to your server and that you would look at [storage best practies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966534.aspx)

Comment: I have extended the disk size and This issue has been solved.